# ElFinder - disable drag and drop for directories

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Does anyone know how to disable drag and drop functionality for ElFinder 2.x? As far as I know this is not controllable through initialization parameters (feel free to double check this), but we've removed some code in tree.js that took care of drag and drop for files:

From tree.js:

```
/**
         * Navigation tree
         *
         * @type JQuery
         */
        tree = $(this).addClass(treeclass)
            // make dirs draggable and toggle hover class

            /* DISABLE DRAGGABLE
            .delegate('.'+navdir, 'hover', function(e) {
                var link  = $(this), 
                    enter = e.type == 'mouseenter';

                if (!link.is('.'+dropover+' ,.'+disabled)) {
                    enter && !link.is('.'+root+',.'+draggable+',.elfinder-na,.elfinder-wo') && link.draggable(fm.draggable);
                    link.toggleClass(hover, enter);
                }
            })*/

            // add/remove dropover css class
            .delegate('.'+navdir, 'dropover dropout drop', function(e) {
                $(this)[e.type == 'dropover' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](dropover+' '+hover);
            })
            // open dir or open subfolders in tree
            .delegate('.'+navdir, 'click', function(e) {
                var link = $(

 ...... // rest of code ommitted
```

This disabled file drag and drop, but not folders. To do that I commented out another delegate in cwd.js, but that ruined the double click event to open a folder - so I am now working on that problem. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to share.

Comment out the following around line 670 in cwd.js:

```
.delegate(fileSelector, 'mouseenter.'+fm.namespace, function(e) {
            var $this = $(this),
            target = list ? $this : $this.children();

            if (!$this.is('.'+clTmp) && !target.is('.'+clDraggable+',.'+clDisabled)) {
            target.draggable(fm.draggable); 
            }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer, and it was so easy that I am embarrassed when I think about how long it took me to solve it.

Just locate the Draggable options in elFinder.js (around line 465). Remove the appendTo parameter from "body" to "" (empty) and you're done.

Check out this blog post for more details and also how to leave the draggable functionality but stop the actual droppable event: http://blog.degree.no/2012/10/disable-drag-and-drop-in-elfinder-2-x/

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas' answer stops most of the visual effect of drag but does not prevent the action when you drop. I.e. dragging a file to a folder will still move it to that folder even if you can't see the visual effect. To prevent that you need to also add a `return` statement as the first body line of the drop function on line 505 so:

```
            drop : function(e, ui) {
                var dst     = $(this),
```

becomes:

```
            drop : function(e, ui) {
                return;
                var dst     = $(this),
```